# Is this a classification problem or regression problem? And what algorithm can be applied to solve it?

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, keras

Let's say we are selling 3 different flavors of juice (orange, apple and grape), and customers purchase several bottles of juice for a group of people. For the sake of this question, let's assume they select flavors depending on various input data such as season, weather, temperature, etc.. There can be many inputs but let's limit the inputs to 4 in this example. Here is an example of their purchase history:

| Order qty | Input_1 (season) | Input_2 (weather) | Input_3 | Input_4 | orange | apple | grape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | summer | sunny | 78 | adult | 20 | 0 | 30 |
| 30 | winder | rainy | 35 | children | 20 | 10 | 0 |
| 75 | spring | cloudy | 50 | both | 30 | 30 | 15 |

What machine learning algorithm can predict how many of each flavor a customer would purchase given the input parameters? Notice that the total of 3 flavors must add up to the order quantity, and number cannot be less than zero.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share your ideas / findings / code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

It is a regression problem.

You can solve it easily with deep learning: just one-hot encode the categorical features and please normalize numerical values.
X is features 0 to 5 and y is orange apple and grapes features.
Then you can train and predict a deep neural network model.

Tensorflow and Pytorch are good example of deep learning libraries

Comment: With pandas, there is an easy way to solve the encode by doing pandas.get_dummies(DATAFRAME, columns=['season'])

You can use sklearn.StandardScaler for the normalization/standardization part : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html?highlight=standardscaler#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler